# Null pointer exception while publishing BOM model source b2x OR b2xa file to Decision center

Tags: ibm-odm

Thank you for looking at this question.

I'm facing a strange problem while publishing BOM model b2xa source code to Decision center.
I have already a rule app project published on decision center and well tested there.  For one change in BOM method, b2xa file is modified and I tried to publish it to Decision center but it could not publish.

Pop window appears and says "Problem occurred in publishing the BOM" error details says Null pointer exception. No trace in log files. No compilation error while moving BOM.
Sometime even no error occurs and code remains as is.

Please refer attached screen capture. (Sorry it is in Japanese )

Even IBM team is also not getting what exactly going wrong.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You did not actually ask a question...

Comment: Hi
Did you find how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization between Rule Designer and Decision Center is not perfect. Used to be unusable (ODM 8.6), then just terrible (8.7), then not bad (8.8), then only occasional issues (8.9). I've not used 8.10, but sync seems to be getting better, with fewer errors, every release. Publishing something new generally works well. The problems I've seen have been when updating something that already exists in Decision Center. I don't think I've had the problem you describe, when pushing a BOM from RD to DC. But I would be tempted to delete it in DC and try pushing it again. If that is not feasible, perhaps you have a second DC server running that you attempt synchronization with? Doing that could tell you if there is a problem with the BOM in RD or if the problem is with the original DC.

For this kind of problem, it is helpful to know what version of ODM you are using.

Comment: Hi Greg,   Thank you for reply.   I use ODM version 8.8.1,   I have my local DC and another is separate DC server.   Since my all code and code versions resides on DC server, I cannot delete complete project from server and  move it complete as a new project. It will lose my snapshots etc.